# DataGrid column change when null

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, datatable, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using `Infragistics UltraGrid` which acts like a regular `datagrid`.

My grid looks like this :

```
-------------------------
|  Red  |  Blue | Green |
-------------------------
| null  |  null |  null |
-------------------------
```

I'm building a `DataTable` to assign it as a `DataSource` for my grid. My `DataTable` has

- 5 red items
- 2 blue items

When I assign my datasource like this :
 `myGrid.DataSource = myDataTable`  or like this 
`myGrid.SetDataBinding(myTable, Nothing, True)`

I get this grid :

```
------------------
| Red  |   Blue  |
------------------
|   5  |    2    |
------------------
```

When I should have this :

```
---------------------------
| Red  |   Blue  |  Green  |
---------------------------
|   5  |    2    |   null  |
----------------------------
```

Is there some property i'm missing that allows my table to resize to non-null columns ?

Comment: Are you sure that your datatable has three columns named RED,BLUE and GREEN?

Comment: @Steve No my datatable does not have a Green column. But my datagrid has the three ( in the designer ) so I what I want to do is to fill the Red and Blue table columns with the datatable but keep my green column even tough it's not in the datatable

Answer (score 2):

When you set the DataSource property to your DataTable you are replacing the schema information set via the Designer with the schema information of the assigned table.
As far as I know there is no way to preserve that missing column.

However you could re-add the missing columns to the grid using the InitializeLayout event

```
Private Sub myGrid_InitializeLayout(sender As object, _
            e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs)
    Dim b As UltraGridBand = e.Layout.Bands[0];
    if Not b.Columns.Exists("RED") Then
        Dim colRed As UltraGridColumn = b.Columns.Add("RED", "RED");
        colRed.NullText = "Null"
        colRed.Header.VisiblePosition = 0
    End if
    if Not b.Columns.Exists("BLU") Then
        Dim colBlu As UltraGridColumn = b.Columns.Add("BLU", "BLU");
        colBlu.NullText = "Null"
        colBlu.Header.VisiblePosition = 1
    End if
    if Not b.Columns.Exists("GREEN") Then
        Dim colGreen As UltraGridColumn = b.Columns.Add("GREEN", "GREEN");
        colGreen.NullText = "Null"
        colGreen.Header.VisiblePosition = 2
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks i'm sure this is what i'll hae to do .. !

Comment: Steve is correct that there isn't any way to preserve the schema information from the designer since the schema didn't match the data source that you are bound to.  In this case a simpler solution would be to always add the "GREEN" column to the DataTable if the column is expected to be there which is what I would assume if you are adding the column in the designer.

Comment: @alhalama, yes, I agree with you that it will be preferable to add to the datatable before binding. However, something on the OP question has drive my thoughts to a  table obtained from a Group by query where also RED and BLU columns could be missing. So I have showed the UltraGrid way of handling the situation

Comment: @Steve, even if the red or blue columns could be missing, the DataTable could still be modified in the same way before data binding by adding the columns.  Note that this would allow you to write only a single line of code to add the column and then the settings set in the designer would be retained so you wouldn't need to reapply any of those settings.